# Does asking a user to watch a rewarded video without a reward violate AdMobs policy

Tags: admob

I would like to add a none invasive button to my free app that would display an AdMob rewarded video. The button would say something simply along the lines of 'Support the app developers, watch an ad!' 
The user would never be forced into pressing this button. However there would be no reward for the user for watching it. Would this violate AdMob policy? If so, can I get round the policy by making a reward for pressing this button?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question, the [policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en&ref_topic=7384517) states:

> Publishers may not encourage users to engage with rewarded ads using phrases that indicate the ad engagement will help the publisher directly, such as “support us” or similar language.